# Translating sqlite3 timestamp format on Windows

Tags: database, sqlite, unix-timestamp

Sorry if this sounds like a puzzle, but it does have puzzling me for a while. :)

From a sqlite3 db file, one of the record has `last_visit_time` field of value `13010301178000000` (INTEGER type).

How come `13010301178000000 = 4/12/2013 9:32:58PM`? (`4/12/2013 9:32:58PM` is got by an existing tool, which I know nothing about how it translates internally).

Can someone shed some light on how this is translated?

I've looked at http://www.epochconverter.com/, but had no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

January 1, 1601 is the epoch for [Windows timestamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx).

However, those timestamps use 100-nanosecond intervals, so it appears your value got divided by 10, or you're missing a zero for some reason.

To convert to/from Unix timestamps, divide/multiply by 1000000 to convert between second and microseconds, and adjust be the offset between 1970 and 1601 in seconds.